# adding items to Cart. Angular js, ionic

Tags: angularjs

Trying to get the product in the product detail page in the app to compile in the shopping cart.  The button works and directs to the cart page but the product or any details is not displayed.

**Product_detail.html** -

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-content class="header-background">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center">
        <h1 class="title">{{cate.name}}</h1>
        <button class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-android-close" ng-click="closeModal()"></button>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <form>
        <div class="product-header" style="background: url({{product.imgLg}}) no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
            <h2 class="product-name">{{product.name}}</h2>
            <div class="product-price">{{product.price}}</div>
            <div class="product-like">
                <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="doLike()">
                    <i class="ion-heart"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
            <div class="product-info">
                 Efficiently customize corporate sources after user-centric internal or "organic".
            </div>
            <div class="product-quantity">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Quantity Here...">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart">
                <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="doOrder({{product.id}})">
                    Add to Cart
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-favorites">
                <button class="button button-block button-dark">
                    Add to Favorites
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

**The Shopping Cart. html.**

```
<ion-view view-title="Shopping cart">
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-light">
    <ion-nav-bar align-title="center">
        <ion-nav-buttons>
            <button class="button button-clear button-icon" ng-click="goBack()" ><i class="ion-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="cate-lv2">
        <div class="card cate-lv2-item" ng-repeat="carts" ng-controller="ProductMenuCtrl">
            <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
                <img ng-src={{product.img}} />
```

**Controller**

```
//function to add the product to the shopping cart
$scope.doOrder = function ($id) {
    $state.go("app.shopping_cart");
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.closeModal();
    });
};

**This is the services.js** 



**Values for the service**  in service.js   

app.factory('Cates', function() {

//This is where you change the product menu front page info.

 app.factory('Cates', function() {
//This is where you change the product menu front page info.
var cates = [{
id: 4,
class: 'item-5',
img: 'img/category/5.jpg',
name: 'Special drinks',
lastText: 'Enthusiastically architect.'
 }];

 return {
all: function() {
  return cates;
},
get: function(cateId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < cates.length; i++) {
    if (cates[i].id === parseInt(cateId)) {
      return cates[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
  }
 };
});

app.service('Products', function() {
var products = [{
    id: 5,
    cateId: 0,
    img: 'img/product/thumb6.jpg',
    imgLg: 'img/product/6.jpg',
    name: 'BROWN RICE WITH GARLIC AND LIME',
    price: '$5.00',
    like: '738'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    cateId: 0,
    img: 'img/product/thumb7.jpg',
    imgLg: 'img/product/7.jpg',
    name: 'OMELETTE WITH ASPARAGUS, BEANS AND THYME',
    price: '$24.00',
    like: '1029'
  }, {
    id: 7,
    cateId: 1,
    img: 'img/product/thumb8.jpg',
    imgLg: 'img/product/8.jpg',
    name: 'FRIED MASHED POTATOES',
    price: '$24.00',
    like: '1029'
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return products;
    },
    get: function(productId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].id === parseInt(productId)) {
          return products[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    getByCate: function(cateId) {
      var product_cate = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].cateId === parseInt(cateId)) {
            product_cate.push(products[i]);
        }
      }
        return product_cate;
    }
  };
});

app.service('Carts', function() {
var carts = [{
id: 0,
cateId: 0,
img: 'img/product/thumb1.jpg',
imgLg: 'img/product/1.jpg',
name: 'BEET ROOT AND RED BEAN VEGAN BURGERS',
price: '$10.00',
qty: '3'
 }, {
id: 8,
cateId: 1,
img: 'img/product/thumb9.jpg',
imgLg: 'img/product/9.jpg',
name: 'CREAMY MUSHROOM SOUP',
price: '$35.00',
qty: '4'
}];

return {
all: function() {
return carts;
}
};
});
```

Comment: you should provide more code and things you did! and explain what are you trying to do

Comment: Yes sorry, first question here. i will have to post another question when it lets me with more code.  Im trying to get the ng click on the product detail page to pass the information of the product to the shopping cart.  Ive tried so many things and i cannot find anything online that i can get to work.

Comment: edit this question

Comment: It will direct to the cart but will not display the product info.

Comment: you can try using factory, service or rootscope

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Im sure there is something i am missing in here to make it work properly.

Comment: i dont see where you set the values to the service

Comment: Added the values where the service comes from.

Comment: I thought that, being on the product page, it wouldn't need to revert to these values for the products.  Or should i list all of the products in that service section.  ?

Comment: you should pass the product id and then go the the cates service and get the item by id? if i  understand right?

Comment: Im not exactly sure how to do that correctly through the controller.

Comment: check this plnkr its an idea https://plnkr.co/edit/ZBrV6zgePhp8OiKCNhRb?p=preview